# Masonry grid not loading correctly and columns are too wide

Tags: jquery, html, css

[link to page](http://www.scrubsandbeyond.com/bold-colors.aspx)

Hello! I am trying to get this masonry grid to show up correctly, meaning equal space on all sides and it should stack evenly like [here](http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-21%20at%209.35.44%20AM?$graphics$&scl=1).

When the page first loads, it looks like [this](http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-21%20at%209.46.05%20AM?$graphics$&scl=1). All of the boxes are collapsed on top of each other and it's like there's a missing column after each one. When you refresh the page, it looks like [this](http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-21%20at%209.47.13%20AM?$graphics$&scl=1), which is exactly what i'm looking for except there should be 4 columns at full width but it only shows as 2, same as last time.. it's like there's a margin in between the columns as opposed to just having another column there like there should be. The spacing below the boxes is exactly what i'm going for on all sides.

Here is my code:

Script tag

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js">    </script>
```

HTML/jQuery:

```
<div id="MainContent" class="fullwidth">
<div style="width: 100%;height:20px;clear:both;"></div>
<div class="title">BOLD COLORS</div>
<div class="subtitle">Scrubs & Beyond Lookbook</div>


<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
Here is one with just a little bit of text

</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
 Here is one with just a little bit of text, plus a lot more text so we can get a good idea of how these things are going to stack eventually
</div>
 <div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-box grid-item">

    <a href="#"><img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/prod1?$graphics$&scl=1"></a>
</div>
</div><!-- end grid -->
<div style="width: 100%;height:20px;clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('.grid').masonry({
// options
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
columnWidth: 290,
gutter: 10
});

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
font-family: "HelveticaNeueW01-65Medi",sans-serif;
color: #e23342;
font-size: 30px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 6px;
}
.subtitle {
font-family: "HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh";
color: #8d5291;
font-size: 20px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
} 
.product-box {
padding: 5px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
float: left;

}
.grid-item { width: 290px; }
.grid {
background: none!important;
}
```

Could someone help me figure out why this isn't showing properly? [The Masonry page I am working from](http://masonry.desandro.com/).
I know it has to be something simple that i'm missing, but I just cannot figure out what it is! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It okay for me. Everything looks as it should. Try another browser

Comment: @HonzaSedloň it's almost correct, there should be 4 columns not 2, but I don't know why it is adding all that space between them

Comment: Still i think, everything is good. Look: https://ctrlv.cz/XJ87
Probably you can have problem with resolution.

Comment: @HonzaSedloň The first row looks good, but the second row 1st item should be all the way to the left, does this make sense? It should be a full grid

Comment: You don't need fitColumns. Just use masonry. And get rid of the margins on product-box, they mess up your layout. Also wrap the whole masonry code in a `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // your code here });` call

Comment: It's so close now! I am only having one issue!
About 25% of the time, the page loads like this: [image](http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-21%20at%2012.33.57%20PM-1?$graphics$&scl=1). Any idea why that would happen? It is live on the link at the top of the post

Comment: @thegreatsloth This is because you don't check if the images are loaded. Use the imagesloaded plugin as described in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.product-box {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   float: left;
   border: 5px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.product-box img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

You shouldn't use margin for the gutters in-between grid items; masonry does not include it in the width of the grid items when it calculates the sizes, and also you already set it as a gutter using jquery.

Comment: I tried this but it still loaded as a collapsed version of itself and then on reload showed up slightly better. but stil not forming the perfect grid

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that often leads to a very annoying situation: The grid works fine on your local machine but as soon as you upload it to your clients server they claim it isn't working and looks horrible. Introducing: Network lag.

**The Reason:**
You can have inconsistent behavior with masonry grids and images if you layout your grid before the images have finished loading. The ways to prevent this is to first initialize the grid, without layout. Then wait until the images are loaded and then layout the grid. You could also set `opacity: 0;` before layout and then change that at the end (note: Don't use `display: none;` because then the element has 0 width and height and the layout won't work).

To check if images are loaded you could use [imagesloaded.js](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

You could also just use the progress method and layout the grid whenever an image is loaded. This is how this would look like:

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 290,
  gutter: 10
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

You find this problem also [in the docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html)

**Edit:** For a masonry layout, try to add the masonry option:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 290,
    gutter: 10
  }
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

Comment: [It is almost working correctly!](http://www.scrubsandbeyond.com/bold-colors.aspx)
If we could just get the second line to go all the way to the left then we would be in business! All of these divs will have different height pictures and different amounts of copy below the images so I just need them to all form one big grid regardless of height

Comment: Which second line? Could you clarify?

Comment: row 2 of the page, for me it's showing up like this [link to image](http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/scrubs/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-21%20at%2011.22.47%20AM?$graphics$&scl=1)

Comment: You have to set the layout options correctly. There are [many different layout modes.](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html). Also check my edit.

Comment: fitColumn would be exactly what i need, could you help me get that one set up?

Comment: You don't need fitColumns. You can also just use masonry. You make a couple of mistakes. You didn't wait until your images are loaded. You didn't wrap your code in `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ // your code here });` You use margins on the grit-item. Only use padding. Otherwise it messes up your layout. Just read the docs, it isn't that difficult.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106934/discussion-between-ole-bjarnstroem-and-thegreatsloth).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
$('.grid').masonry({
// options
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
columnWidth: 300,
gutter: 10

});
});
});
```

I had to add the image loader because images were loaded after the divs and making them overlap. also had to remove margins and only use padding.